# vatab pro 2.0.46 unsetting radio option on tab

Tags: vb6, farpoint

I have a vatabpro control version 2.0.46 by Farpoint technologies in VB6 on a form.

In the form activate event some code is run to show and hide the certain tabs in the va tab pro control.

After this a normal option button on one of the tabs is set to true.

When the form is displayed all the radios on the tab are unchecked even though they were explicitly set in code and I can see this happening on a breakpoint.

I have a weird feeling i've seen this before and suspect it might be something to do with the vatabpro control and hiding tabs or switching between active tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found the answer, it's because the tabs are not treated as separate containers so radios in other tabs were unchecking my radio when they were being set. The solution is to nest the radios within a frame.